# Simple GLFW freezes (thinks like crazy, not stopping)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I've created a very simple implementation of a GLFW window. My implementation looks like so

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Include glfw for window handling
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280;
int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720;

GLFWwindow* window;

int main() {

    if(!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW!\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);


    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Title", NULL, NULL);
    if( !window )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to create window!\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    do {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    } while(!glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE));

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine, but when I run the application it just "freezes", not showing the correct clear color or anything. It just thinks like crazy (that "thinking"-cursor icon in Windows 7 spins and never stops).
I'm wondering why it freezes like such, does anyone have an idea?

**EDIT:**
Found the solution to my problem. I was learning from a GLFW2 example, but having the newest version (GLFW3) required me to redo the code some; the thing I didn't realize was that the glSwapBuffers(window) call doens't call glfwPollEvents() by itself, giving me the problem I had.

Comment: I notice your code is not equal to the example in GLFW's documentation. Does that one also freeze? http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html

Comment: I'm following the examples from this webpage: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/. But let me check it out tomorrow and I will respons (on my way to bed :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're not clearing the buffers, hence the clear colour is not showing through.
2. You're not adding any kind of delay, so you're swapping empty buffers flat out ("thinking like crazy").

Comment: I found the tutorials I'm "following" on www.opengl-tutorial.org and their example doesn't call glClear() nor do they add a delay (how would you best add a delay?).

Comment: And they seem to run fine for some reason. Which is why I am so confused. :)

Comment: You seem to be missing some lines of code.  Take their example exactly as it is, and then make modification.

Comment: Found my problem, the example I'm following uses a GLFW version below 3. In GLFW3 they changed it so that glfwSwapBuffers(...) deosn't call glfwPollEvents(), so one has to do that manually. So basically you're right in that functionality was missing, but it was missing because of a function splitup from GLFW2 -> GLFW3.

Comment: By the way, GLEW and GLM are libraries that helps determine which OpenGL extensions are available on the platform (GLEW) and for doing 3D math (GLM), so they were left out because they weren't needed yet :)